# Why does python's numba run 2D array program on Spyder but not on remote server?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numba

I created a small program that uses numba on a method containing a 2D array (list of lists). This program runs just fine on Spyder, but when I try to run the exact same program on a remote Ubuntu server, I get a long error saying "unsupported nested memory-managed object" (listed below the program code).

The code:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def test():
    num1 = 10
    num2 = 5
    array = [ [ 1 for i in range(num1) ] for j in range(num2) ]
    #array = [2 for i in range(num1) ]
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0,num1):
        for j in range(0,num2):
            sum = sum + array[i][j]
    print(sum)

test()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/runtime/context.py", line 186, in _call_incref_decref
    meminfo = data_model.get_nrt_meminfo(builder, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/datamodel/models.py", line 329, in get_nrt_meminfo
    "unsupported nested memory-managed object")
NotImplementedError: unsupported nested memory-managed object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/errors.py", line 243, in new_error_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 216, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 263, in lower_inst
    self.storevar(val, inst.target.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 928, in storevar
    self.decref(fetype, old)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 982, in decref
    self.context.nrt.decref(self.builder, typ, val)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/runtime/context.py", line 208, in decref
    self._call_incref_decref(builder, typ, typ, value, "NRT_decref")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/runtime/context.py", line 179, in _call_incref_decref
    funcname, getters + (getter,))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/runtime/context.py", line 188, in _call_incref_decref
    raise NotImplementedError("%s: %s" % (root_type, str(e)))
NotImplementedError: list(list(int64)): unsupported nested memory-managed object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2DArrayTest.py", line 15, in <module>
    test()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 307, in _compile_for_args
    return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 579, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 80, in compile
    flags=flags, locals=self.locals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 740, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 360, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 699, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 686, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 246, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 238, in run
    stage()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 621, in stage_nopython_backend
    self._backend(lowerfn, objectmode=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 576, in _backend
    lowered = lowerfn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 563, in backend_nopython_mode
    self.flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 858, in native_lowering_stage
    lower.lower()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 135, in lower
    self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 176, in lower_normal_function
    entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 201, in lower_function_body
    self.lower_block(block)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 216, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/errors.py", line 249, in new_error_context
    six.reraise(type(newerr), newerr, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/errors.py", line 243, in new_error_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 216, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 263, in lower_inst
    self.storevar(val, inst.target.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 928, in storevar
    self.decref(fetype, old)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 982, in decref
    self.context.nrt.decref(self.builder, typ, val)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/runtime/context.py", line 208, in decref
    self._call_incref_decref(builder, typ, typ, value, "NRT_decref")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/runtime/context.py", line 179, in _call_incref_decref
    funcname, getters + (getter,))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numba/runtime/context.py", line 188, in _call_incref_decref
    raise NotImplementedError("%s: %s" % (root_type, str(e)))
numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
list(list(int64)): unsupported nested memory-managed object
File "2DArrayTest.py", line 7
[1] During: lowering "$56 = build_list(items=[])" at 2DArrayTest.py (7)
```

I have seen elsewhere that numba doesn't like 2D arrays and lists of lists because of memory. Is there a way to make it work on the remote server, since it works on Spyder? What is it that Spyder does differently to make it work?

Comment: Are you using the same Numba version in both environments?

Comment: AFAIK Numba does not support lists of lists (at least not that way) and so the resulting code is not compliant. Even if it would be, this approach is not efficient. Using Numpy arrays is generally efficient. Basides this, if the result differ, it might be due to a new experimental support of Numba in one of the two environment. Finally, please prefer not using `sum` (which is a built-in function) for a variable name.

Comment: @aerobiomat Yes, both are the same versions, I downloaded them around the same time

Comment: @JérômeRichard Why would Spyder run the program just fine then if the lists of lists is not supported?

Comment: If the version are exactly the same (using `numba.version_info`), then I do not know. I tested the code on my machine and it build (but do not run correctly). Thus, the new version of Numba should actually support this finally. Note that the current program is ill formed: it segfault because the dimensions do not mach with the loop (unless j and i are swap). With this fix, the code run correctly on my machine.